# How to get the value from a cell when table row is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the href value from the cell with the class `editlink`. This is what I have tried but I'm getting `undefined` in the `alert`.

```html
<table id="table_1">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>sometext</td>
      <td class="editlink"><a href="/linkid444">edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sometext2</td>
      <td class="editlink"><a href="/linkid555">edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table_1").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
    var linkdata = $(this).closest('tr').find('.editlink').attr("href");
    alert(linkdata);
  });
});
```

Comment: `delegate` has been deprecated for some time. Don't use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly note that `delegate()` has been deprecated. Instead, use the delegated signature of the `on()` method. This may also mean that you need to upgrade the version of jQuery you're using.

As for the issue you have, it's because `.editlink` is the `td`. The `href` property is on the `a` element, so the selector needs to be `.editlink a`. Also, `closest('tr')` is redundant, as the event handler is already bound to the `tr`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table_1").on('click', "tr", function() {
    var linkdata = $(this).find('.editlink a').attr("href");
    console.log(linkdata);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_1">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>sometext</td>
      <td class="editlink"><a href="/linkid444">edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sometext2</td>
      <td class="editlink"><a href="/linkid555">edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```